# How do I add 2 days in number of days from JdateChooser?

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I need to take a date from user using JdateChooser then Increment in the days of that date by 2 then save the date in database.

I am using eclipse and this is the code I am trying;

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String ADate=df.format(dateChooser.getDate());
Date date =  df.parse(ADate);  //Error comes here
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                  
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
Date futureDate = cal.getTime();
String outD=df.format(futureDate); //And also here
System.out.println(outD);
```

I always get error:

> java.util.date can not be cast to java.sql.date

Answer (score 2):

It must be only a wrong import issue. Check that you are using

```
import java.util.Date;
```

and not

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

The `parse()` method of [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) returns `java.util.Date`.